# Dynamic NSCombobox

Tags: xcode, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nscombobox

I'm creating an application in which I have several entities and now I need to filter the content of third combobox dynamically. I explain myself better. I have 3 combobox (building, floor and department), I would like first to show me all the buildings included, but the second should show only selected before the plans for the building, the last I should be select only the departments of the building and the plan you choose. How can I do this? To simplify attaching some photos.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply drill down with predicates, if you use single fetch requests to Core Data.

However, your relationships are not set up correctly. For example, there is an `edificio` attribute in `Particelle`. If it refers to an building, it should be a *relationship* to a `Edifici` object, not some kind of foreign key. There are no foreign keys in Core Data, just relationships.

If you do this, everything becomes much easier by using a `NSFetchedResultsController`. You can now simply traverse the object graph without any specific fetching.

The scheme could be something like this (maybe need to change the order):

```
Anno <--->> Particella <---->> Edificio <---->> AreaRischio
```

Now you can simply tell the fetched results controller to start fetching all `Anno` entities. Then you drill down with simple dot notation:

```
NSSet *listForNextTable = selectedAnnoObject.particelle;
```

and further with

```
NSSet *listForNextTable = selectedParticellaObject.edifici;
```

etc. You see, it gets really simple.